# Proper shingle placement in corner

Tags: roof, gutters

I had my roof replaced about a month ago and recently noticed that when it rains, a strong stream of water pours from the roof onto an adjacent window in the corner. In this problem area, I have one gutter stacked on top of another rather than a single gutter with a corner fitting in it, I guess because the fascia is higher on one side of the corner. It looks like the way the shingles are laid is causing water coming down the valley to get behind the top gutter and pour onto the window. The roofer came out to take a look and basically said that the shingles are laid properly and my gutter design is going to cause some water to get by. Below are some pictures of the problem area. Are these shingles properly placed for this situation? Is there anything I can do about the water getting past here? I'm concerned that the concentration of water is going to cause the window/siding to rot.

[image]

[image]

Edit: adding images from further away as requested.

Here is an image with a red circle around the gap where water is getting past the gutters:

[image]

And here's an image from below with a red arrow pointing from the gap where the water is coming out to the window that it is pouring on:

[image]

Comment: Please back up a bit and show us more context. It's hard to get a sense of the scene from so close up. Make sure the photos display in the correct orientation.

Comment: My, my, a well placed piece of flashing would do wonders for the situation. Yes the roof is laid properly, but the roofer could have started the short course 3 inches lower and there would have been no problem. Did the roof have this problem before?

Comment: @Jack, no, this problem wasn't present before the re-roof. I just talked to the roofer and it turns out there was a breakdown in communication through his secretary and he was under the impression that I was having problems with water jumping the gutters in heavy rain. He's going to take another look today and hopefully realize the issue.